# PHP PDO count and sum value from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Well, I'm pretty sure this is just a novice question, so please forgive me for that, but I feel like I'm losing my mind.

I have a simple MySQL rating table and I need to count rows and to sum rates values (int) with PHP PDO

```
$sql = "SELECT rate FROM rating_table";
$query = $db->query($sql);            

$rate_times = count($query->fetchAll()); // it works! 
echo '<p>'.$rate_times.'</p>';

$sum_rates = array_sum($query->fetchAll()); // it doesn't work!
echo '<p>'.$sum_rates.'</p>';
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestion

Comment: array_sum probably stumbles for a multidimensional array

Comment: Would you print here fetchAll() array out put?

Comment: @naf4me here for you: 

array(78) {
    [0]=> array(1) { ["rate"]=> int(4) } 
    [1]=> array(1) { ["rate"]=> int(5) } 
    [2]=> array(1) { ["rate"]=> int(3) }
    ....
    [77]=> array(1) { ["rate"]=> int(5) }
    }

Comment: using mysql functions `sum` and `count` is much better solution (and faster too)

Comment: Array_sum sums the array like : $a = [1,4,6,8,4]. array_sum($a) will output 23.

Comment: Understood. Thx guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, all you have to do is to modify your sql request, this will return a single row

```
sql = "SELECT sum(rate) as rate_sum, count(*) as record_count FROM rating_table";
$query = $db->query($sql);            
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($row) {
  $sum = $row['rate_sum'];
  $count = $row['record_count'];
}
```